# PHP file_get_contents() behaves differently to browser

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to download the contents of a web page using PHP.
When I issue the command:

```
$f = file_get_contents("http://mobile.mybustracker.co.uk/mobile.php?searchMode=2");
```

It returns a page that reports that the server is down. Yet when I paste the same URL into my browser I get the expected page.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this? Does file_get_contents transmit any headers that differentiate it from a browser request?

Answer (score 21):

Yes, there are differences -- the browser tends to send plenty of additionnal [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers), I'd say ; and the ones that are sent by both probably don't have the same value.

Here, after doing a couple of tests, **it seems that passing the HTTP header called `Accept` is necessary**.

This can be done using the third parameter of `file_get_contents`, to specify additionnal context informations :

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        //'user_agent '  => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100301 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.6",
        'header' => array(
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8
'
        ), 
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$f = file_get_contents("http://mobile.mybustracker.co.uk/mobile.php?searchMode=2", false, $context);
echo $f;
```

With this, I'm able to get the HTML code of the page.

Notes :

- I first tested passing the `User-Agent`, but it doesn't seem to be necessary *-- which is why the corresponding line is here as a comment*
- The value is used for the `Accept` header is the one Firefox used when I requested that page with Firefox before trying with `file_get_contents`.

  - Some other values might be OK, but I didn't do any test to determine which value is the required one.

For more informations, you can take a look at :

- [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)
- [`stream_context_create`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)
- [Context options and parameters](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/context.php)
- **[HTTP context options](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)** *-- that's the interesting page, here ;-)*

Answer (score -4):

replace all spaces with %20