# Error using file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Has anybody seen this before. If I go to a page (http://thamessailingclub.co.uk/news.php?Type=News&Source=Google%20Boating%20News) and look at the page source, there are no errors. However, if retrieve the url in PHP using:

`file_get_contents($url) ;`

...there are (SQL) errors on the page! Weird how can the SQL return errors in one case and not the other? This is breaking my test suite.

Comment: Well, I built it, but I can't be blamed for the design :-)

Comment: D'Oh - I've sorted this. Basically the URL had spaces in, so was failing. The answer was on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548451/php-file-get-contents-behaves-differently-to-browser. Lots of interesting stuff in your answers tho' guys, so thanks for that...

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and select it as the accepted answer. You won't be able to upvote it but it will appear as the accepted solution and allow the question to fall off of the "unanswered" question lists.

Answer (score 1):

90% of probabilty it's an issue related to HTTP Headers. file_get_contents doesn't send all the headers that a browser do and that could broke some query.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the site checks the user agent, and has a bug when serving up content for something other than Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft IE, etc. You could change your PHP user agent with the following:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'agent_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your browser contain some kind of session cookie that is affecting the page you are loading? Does the page need you to be logged in for instanace?