# php file_get_contents($url) not returning same results as url in addressbar

Tags: php, file-get-contents

when I copy and paste the following url in the address bar, it opens the page correctly:

https://www.lacourt.org/casesummary/ui/casesummary.aspx?CaseNumber=BC510457

but the following code returns a case not found message from the site when I run it on localhost:

```
    <?php
    $url = 'https://www.lacourt.org/casesummary/ui/casesummary.aspx?CaseNumber=BC510457';
    echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Why is file_get_contents not returning the same page as when I type the url directly in the address bar? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Uses curl instead of file_get_content

Comment: Thank you but I've already tried that and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP file\_get\_contents() behaves differently to browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548451/php-file-get-contents-behaves-differently-to-browser)

Comment: I already checked that link before posting my question. It's not applicable.

Comment: The site needs cookies to work. When you tried using `curl`, did you set `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`? And also `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`?

Answer (score 0):

first, i can't connect the url,
but you can try set `user-agent` in request header.
like this :)

`

```
$url = 'https://www.lacourt.org/casesummary/ui/casesummary.aspx?CaseNumber=BC510457';
$header = [
'header'=>[
'method'=>'GET',
'header'=>['user-agent'=>'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36']
]
];
$ctx = stream_context_create($header);
echo file_get_contents($url,false,$ctx);
```

`

Comment: Thank you but I already tried that as well. I get the same result (case not found page).